# Change negative values in dataframe column to absolute value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4      Col5      Col6
1   1982      0      0   -211       107         0
2   4412      0    989      0       296         0
3      0  -5051      0   -267       389       920
4      0  -2983      0   -215         0      1639
5      0  -1326      0   -861         0         0
6   3722      0     89      0       243     13349
```

How can I change the negative values to their absolute values?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
abs(dat)
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: +1. I thought of doing that but just assumed it would convert it all to a `matrix` first and went my silly `lapply` way...

Answer (score 8):

You can just do something like the following (assuming your original `data.frame` is called "mydf"):

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, abs)
mydf
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5  Col6
# 1 1982    0    0  211  107     0
# 2 4412    0  989    0  296     0
# 3    0 5051    0  267  389   920
# 4    0 2983    0  215    0  1639
# 5    0 1326    0  861    0     0
# 6 3722    0   89    0  243 13349
```

Comment: @Cybernetic, no problem. Sven's answer is better anyway :-)

Comment: Thus his checkmark...but thank you very much for your solution as well.

Comment: @Cybernetic, a subtle difference is that if you wanted to only replace negative values in a couple of rows (say 1 and 2), this is very easy with this `lapply` approach: `mydf[1:2] <- lapply(mydf[1:2], abs)`.

Comment: And, really surprisingly, this approach comes out a tiny bit faster than just `abs(mydf)`, if you are discerning enough to be able to detect a few milliseconds of difference :-)

Comment: @AHandcartAndMohair What should be the approach if we want to take log2 of a dataframe having negative values. I am trying this: `B <- ifelse(MEPEryA_TD == 0, 1, log2(MEPEryA_TD) & ifelse(MEPEryA_TD < 0, -log2(abs(MEPEryA_TD)), log2(MEPEryA_TD)))` but it is not working. What I want to do is if number = 0 then change it to 1 and take log2, if number < 0 then take log2 of absolute value and assign the negative number to it and if number > 0 then take log2 of the number.

Comment: This answer by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 is better when we have some string variables/columns example: `a %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% lapply(abs)`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dataframe that consists of a mix of both `numeric` and `character` columns:

```
#dataframe is your original dataframe. 

abs.dat <- data.frame %>% 
  dplyr::select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  abs()
```

Only select numeric columns.